# ASP.NET How to Maintain Scroll Position within a Datagrid After Postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an aspx page containing a datagrid.  This datagrid is populated in the code-behind via a SQL query and can have anywhere from 1 to 1000 rows.

Users can click on each row and edit the data for that row.  Once they save, however, the datagrid scrolls back to the top, no matter where they were.  I would like to maintain the scroll position within the datagrid so the user can easily edit the next row.  I have the following on my aspx page:

```
<script src="common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

        function setScroll(val) {
            document.getElementById("hidscrollPos").value = val.scrollTop;
        }

        function scrollTo(what) {
            document.getElementById(what).scrollTop =
        document.getElementById("hidscrollPos").value;
        }
</script>

<body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout" onload="javascript:scrollTo('divDataGrid')">
<form id="form1" method="post" runat="server">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel4" style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 354px" runat="server">
<div id="divDataGrid" style="overflow:scroll;" onscroll="javascript:setScroll(this);">
    <asp:DataGrid ID="grdItem" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" style="position: absolute; top: 50px" 
        CssClass="grdGrid" Font-Size="X-Small" GridLines="None" Width="97%" 
        Height="4px" CellPadding="1">


</asp:DataGrid>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
<input type="hidden" id="hidscrollPos" name="scrollPos" value="0" runat="server" />
</form>
</body>
```

Within the datagrid I have defined 11 asp:TemplateColumns that I think (hope?) are not relevant to this issue.  I can certainly add in that code if need be.

My .css file has this for grdGrid:

```
.grdGrid
{
FONT-SIZE: 12px;
FONT-FAMILY: Verdana;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: white
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and IE9.  Users will be using either IE8 or IE9.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should take a look at http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/  might help. http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-from-scratch/ ....search for getScrollingPosition() ..its a good article

Comment: Very helpful article, Scorpio.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After beating my head against the wall for hours, I finally figured it out.

The code posted above is correct and works perfectly.  The problem was that divDataGrid was contained within another div, and THAT div had overflow:auto set.  So the scroll bar I was seeing was from that div, not divDataGrid or grdItem.

Once I removed the overflow:auto setting from the previous div everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap the datagrid in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: I've never used an UpdatePanel and know nothing about them.  Looks like I can't put the datagrid inside it?