# How to maintain scroll position of specific page on postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have grid to display data by row and for this I have used a user control to display each row and if I will go to bottom of page and click on row then it will redirect to view page for that particular row and then if i click on back link then I want my page position back. Please assist asap.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using AJAX plugins like AJAX Controls Toolkit, eso.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007190/asp-net-how-to-maintain-scroll-position-within-a-datagrid-after-postback

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to build in bookmarks in both the usercontrol and also the back link.

Go here and scroll down to bookmarks.  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: In user control .ascx page I have added <a name="MOVEHERE"></a> and that page .ascx.cs (code page)

I have added 
if (IsPostBack)            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#MOVEHERE';", true); Is it right or do i need to add any code in page where this user control is used?

on my view page there is link "back" to take it to previous page.
what shall I do there?